# Update based on select from INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Tags: mysql, select, information-schema

I have this query:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE column_name LIKE 'organization_id'
```

Based on the result, I want to update all the returned tables with 'organization_id' = something; Something like this:

```
UPDATE (above query results) SET `organization_id` = 'something'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a job for Dynamic SQL .

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT('UPDATE ',t.table_name,' SET organization_id = <ID> ;')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE column_name LIKE 'organization_id'
```

Then copy the output and execute it.

Comment: Thanks. The actual code is this: `SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT('UPDATE ',t.table_name,' SET organization_id = 1 ;')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS t
WHERE column_name LIKE 'organization_id'`